# Compare CSS file with Common.Css and remove existing rules

Tags: node.js, node-modules, tailwind-css

I have common.css file with some rules and some separate css files, I need to remove rules that exist in common.css from separate.css files. Is anyone knows is there any npm module or other solution to do it?